# VSCode: Snippet - Transform characters to another equal length line

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, bnf, vscode-snippets

What I would like:
A snippet, call that `Bound Line`. When I trigger that snippet and type something like:

```
This is my line
```

and hit tab, it should print:

```
This is my line
    C
***************
```

'C' where the cursor should be and "****" line is exactly same number of characters as the first line.  After looking over the BNF for transformations at [Microsoft Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables), I came up with the following which is horribly, horribly wrong:

```
"Bound Line" : {
        "prefix" : "bl",
        "body": [
            "${2:}",
            "\t$3"
            "${2/(.*)/${1:/[a-zA-Z0-9:,;*_]/*/gi}"
        ]
    }
```

If you have some insights, I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is the cursor at `C`? What is special about that position?

Comment: One tab - or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Bound Line" : {
  "prefix" : "bl",
  "body": [
      "$1",
      "\t$0",
      "${1/./*/g}"
  ]
}
```

Just replace every character with an `*` in the transform.  The `g` global flag means it will repeat that for each character.  The cursor ends up at the `$0` position.

[image: demo of transform to equal length]